# How to run urxvt terminal with the default yum shell command in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, rxvt, urxvt

I want to run the urxvt terminal that should start with yum shell commands by default, But I am getting a problem to integrate it with the PyQt5. this is the class EmbTerminal that is called when a button is clicked to run yum shell. I want that terminal should start with it. This is the code that I am using to embed urxvt terminal with PyQt5. I want to what should I change in it to run yu, shell by default in it when it is called.

```
class EmbTerminal(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        self.process = QtCore.QProcess(self)
        self.terminal = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.terminal)
        self.setFixedSize(555,425)
        self.process.start('urxvt',['-embed', str(int(self.winId()))])
```

I tried to change

```
self.process.start('urxvt',['-embed', str(int(self.winId()))])
```

with

```
self.process.start('urxvt yum shell ',['-embed', str(int(self.winId()))])
```

but it shows blank screen without urxvt terminal.

Comment: What do you mean by *yum shell*? As far as I know "yum" is a command that comes in RedHat based distros

Comment: yum shell is a command that start shell of yum in it like when we run python3 its interpreter starts.